# Wild segmentation fault while using gpg

Tags: apt, updates, gnupg

I'm having a problem while updating.
When I execute `sudo apt-get update`I get a lot of errors like

```
The next keys couldn't be verified because their public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

So I run `apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`

but I get

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.h6c2gBEFf0/gpg.1.sh --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 19 firmas no comprobadas por falta de claves
gpg: clave 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: clave pública "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" importada
gpg: Total quantity processed: 1
gpg:                 imported: 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and when I try to update again I get exactly the same errors. I have tried a lot of solutions so maybe I have messed up something.

The error also shows up, for example, when I execute

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

which gives

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

*EDIT0:*
I booted memtest and ran a complete test with good [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mXmn.jpg); no errors found. Then I booted a live lubuntu 18.10 and executed `fsck` which gave

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -M /dev/sda7
fsck from util-linux 2.32
e2fsck 1.44.4 (18-Aug-2018)
/dev/sda7: clean, 328959/1250928 files, 2710797/4999936 blocks

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ echo $?
0
```

where `/dev/sda7` is the partition of my hard drive where I have installed lubuntu 18.04. Yet when I execute `apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32` it gives the same error as above :(
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for one complete pass. Then also do a `fsck`.

Comment: I downloaded the official lubuntu 18.10 .iso file and created a bootable USB pendrive with the Linux Live USB Creator I had by default on lubuntu 18.04, and when I boot it I get three options but there is no "memtest" option. What should I do?

Comment: Try booting to your normal GRUB screen, and see if you find memtest there. If not, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download it there.

Comment: I did what you suggested @heynnema and I have posted the results. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Boot to Ubuntu, start the `terminal`, and type `sudo debsums -s` and watch for any errors that would indicate any file corruption or modifications. FYI: fsck should be run with `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7`.

Comment: So, @heynnema , I (of course) couldn't `sudo apt install debsums` so I downloaded all dependencies from packages.ubuntu. Finally, executing what you suggested wasn't possible and `apt` even suggested `apt --fix-broken install` which asks to delete a lot of packages and warns about damaging the system. I have `/home` mounted on a different partition since I have had to reinstall Lubuntu like four or five times because of the same problem. Do you think I should simply reinstall again? Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Try this, start the `Disks` app, and go to the "hamburger" icon, and select `SMART Data & Tests`. In the data, look for any item with the word "sector" in it, run the tests, and report back. When you installed lubuntu in the past, did you verify a good download before you built your USB drive?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I dual-boot with Windows 10 Pro but since I nearly haven't used it I did not install any drivers to handle ext# partitions. About the tests, there are "Relcoated sectors list", "Relocations counter", "Pending sectors counter" and "Incorrigible sectors counter"  should I run all of them? There is "fast" and "long" tests, which one? And no, I didn't verify a good download, I don't know what that is...

Comment: I am downloading lubuntu version 18.04.2, I have 18.04. I should have picked that one in the first place, maybe.

Comment: For the data, give me the values you see for those "sector" parameters, and for the tests, just run the short test. To check if your download went ok, also download the md5sums file, and then `md5sum filename.iso` and compare value with the md5sums file. You can check your original .iso download that way also.

Comment: Don't be in a hurry to reinstall. Any why not install 18.10?

Comment: @heynnema The value on all 4 tests is 0 after running them. I just downloaded `lubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` and I verified it with `sha256sum`: I got exact match. I can't do the same with the .iso file I used before because I don't have it anymore. Now I got a notification saying that I suddenly have 22 broken packages and 24 keys unsigned (it made me laugh).

Comment: And I thought of installing 18.04 because 18.10 brought me problems with my wireless (bluetooth and Wi-Fi), touchpad and keyboard devices. Lubuntu 18.04 works just fine to me, except for this seemingly no reason crashes after a few months of normal use (my experience), and which I have only been able to fix by reinstalling the OS after trying lots of stuff. The same thing has happened to me five or six times per version since 16.04. I don't know, maybe it's me, not her :D

Comment: If you're going to reinstall, backup your data, wipe the disk my installing a new GPT partition table, and then reinstall lubuntu from scratch. Don't reinstall over what's there now... as we know it's a bad foundation.

Comment: OK @heynnema thank you and sorry the bother. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No problem. Leave the question. But do keep me in the loop so that I know you're ok.

Answer (score 0):

The "segmentation fault" error message means that there is most likely a bug in the program/command you executed, in this case "apt-key". It is probably a good idea to report the bug so that it can be fixed:
[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)